# Rerun Failed Test Cases with Cake and NUnit

Tags: c#, powershell, automated-tests, nunit, cakebuild

I am using a cake script to run test cases with NUnit. The cases are written in C#. How can I tell the script to rerun failed test cases? I am also using PowerShell to bootstrap the cake build.

Comment: Did you mean NUnit, and not NuGet? NuGet is a package manager, and NUnit is a unit testing framework.

Comment: Yes, Sorry. NUnit. I Fixed the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NUnit currently doesn't have an out-of-the-box feature to re-run failed tests. You'll have to:

1. Compile a list of failed tests, either by extracting the failed tests from the [Test Result XML file](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/technical-notes/usage/Test-Result-XML-Format.html), or by writing the failed tests to a file by implementing a [custom `IResultWriter`](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit-engine/extensions/Result-Writers.html?q=IResultWriter).
2. Run NUnit giving it the list of tests to execute (the failed tests you got on step 1), using `--test=FULLNAMES` or --`testlist=FILE` as described in the [documentation](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/running-tests/Console-Command-Line.html#options).

> --test=FULLNAMES Comma-separated list of FULLNAMES of tests to run or explore. This option may be repeated. Note that this option is
> retained for backward compatibility. The --where option can now be
> used instead.
>
> --testlist=FILE   The name (or path) of a FILE containing a list of tests to run or explore, one per line.

If you're using the [NUnit3Runner for Cake](https://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Common.Tools.NUnit/NUnit3Settings/), you can configure the `NUnit3Settings` with the tests to be run (`Test` or `TestList`).